# Guitar making weird noise

Tags: guitar, maintenance

I have a normal acoustic Yamaha Guitar (starter version). It was working fine until now (5 months). All of a sudden the 2nd string is making weird noises when picked but only when the 6th string is pressed at the 12th fret or higher. I have no idea why it is happening. Any insights are welcome.

Comment: Can you please describe what "weird noise" it is making?

Comment: It is difficult to describe actually. It is producing the normal sound but beside that there is this irritating noise like bad electronic sound. It can only be heard only when i pick 2nd string and press 6ths string at 12 fret or higher. I can't see the connection. It is loud and clear that something is wrong but why at that particular fret and onwards is surprising.

Comment: Can you record the sound perhaps with a youtube video using a smart phone or other video/sound device? This could be  many things, it would save everyone a lot of time to get a more accurate 'picture' of the event. Endless possibilities: Strings (are these the original 5 month old strings?), Nut (hair caught in nut)? Bridge? Neck alignment? Finger nails too long causing a buzz? Body wrapped? Are the string ends on the tuning machines cut short, or hanging out? Are the strings at the bridge end secure? Loose fret ? etc?

Comment: Wow I didn't even know there could be so much problem. let me try to get the audio online. I'll add the link in that case. Thanks for your reply though.

Comment: @BraddSzonye "normal acoustic Yamaha Guitar"  I don't see any indication of pick up here.

Comment: @filzilla Oops, I saw the “noise like bad electronic sound” and thought he was playing an electric guitar.

Answer (score 1):

This is almost certainly caused by a "cavity" on the silent part of the fingered e-string, resonating at a B frequency. Likely, it's the part between the nut and 7th fret (although the problem should already appear from 8th fret on then, not 12th). To test where exactly, finger one of the problematic notes and pluck the "wrong" part of the E-string at various lower frets. At some spots you'll likely hear that troublemaker sound, at B or perhaps F♯. Identify the outer boundaries of where this works; that is the part where you can directly tackle the problem. For instance, you can file down the upper delimiting fret (just ever so slightly); this will remove it as the undesired "bridge" it makes right now and, if not remove, then at least shift the resonance to a less problematic frequency.

The real problem might be that your neck is bent in such a way the frets are exposed in a problematic way. Consult an expert, maybe the neck can be adjusted to properly solve the problem rather than just removing the symptom.